# How does Pete Graham know who Dr. Douglas Grey's partner was in "Gothika"?

Tags: gothika

At the end of the movie *Gothika* (2003), Pete Graham (Robert Downey Jr.) arrives at the police office immediately after Miranda Grey (Halle Berry) kills Sheriff Ryan (John Carroll Lynch), both knowing that he was the partner-in-crime of Dr. Douglas Grey (Charles S. Dutton).

How did Pete Graham seem to know before seeing the sheriff dead?